# Windows Workflow Strong-Naming Mismatch

Tags: .net, wpf, flash

When I save a workflow XAML file with assembly references, they will be saved with the strong named reference that include the version number.  When I upgrade the application assembly that the XAML file references, the XAML file is no longer valid and cannot open because it says that it's missing the assembly I updated.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Does [assembly binding redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx) for the application solve the issue?

Comment: Rats. Oh well - I'll leave the answer here for the moment so that others can see it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

"cannot open" - in VS2008 ?
I think that binding redirection should work for workflow runtime.

Look at this msdn article about [Versioning Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sl-si/magazine/dd727506(en-us).aspx)